# How to set user Id and propeties in Firebase Analytics - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

- Goal : To save user ID and their properties, as he/she interacts with the ***flutter*** application.
- Problem : Events are getting logged but i cant see user id and properties. I noticed it initially (that user id and properties arre not being logged) while working in debug mode, and then I also waited for 24-48 hours to check in the dashboard but no details for userId.
- Documentation link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid#dart
- and Yes the properties that I am trying to save in analytics, I have defined them in ***Custom definitions*** under User scope.
- Code :

```dart
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';

class AnalyticsClass {
  static final AnalyticsClass _singleton = AnalyticsClass._internal();
  late FirebaseAnalytics fa = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  factory AnalyticsClass() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  AnalyticsClass._internal();

  buttonTap(id, name) async {
    await fa.logEvent(name: 'button_tap');
  }

  setUser(String id, name) async {
    await fa.setUserId(id: id);
    await fa.setUserProperty(name: 'referral', value: "test new : $name");
  }

  resetUser() async {
    await fa.setUserId(id: null);
    await fa.setUserProperty(name: 'referral', value: null);
  }
}
```

Comment: have u found anything regarding this

Comment: nothing till now, for the time being I switched to amplitude.

Comment: I have found a solution these articles helped me first make sure to setUserId() using goole analytics and attach your firebase project from default google analytics to new google analytics project. Go to explorer -> open timeline -> user explorer. 
Now u can see user specific data (This will reflects after some time user generates data)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [setUserId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid) in Firebase, this does not show up in the Analytics reports due to privacy concerns. What you can do is to export your data to [BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). This will allow you to query your raw data as well as build custom reports via [Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7259176). You may also consider using the [User explorer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9283607) in Google Analytics Dashboard which will help you gain more insight on the behavior of your individual users.